# Compare textbox text with sql server name?

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am making a windows form application and i want to compare server's name with the text in the text box, how i can get this server name ?

I am using this code for connection.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=username;" + "password=password;server=serverurl;" + "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + "database=database; " + "connection timeout=30");
```

Comment: Putting a question mark at the end of a statement doesn't turn it into a question. What have you tried? Where are you stumped?

Comment: well i think for beginner its difficult to know what should write and how to ask?

Comment: Do you have a working connection? The server name is one of the properties of your connection object.

Comment: yes i have, i am using this code for connection. 
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=username;" +
                               "password=password;server=serverurl;" +
                               "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                               "database=database; " +
                               "connection timeout=30");

Comment: @user1548346, if your not sure how to ask that's what the [help] section is there for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a SQL Data Source Enumerator or the SqlConnection object Database property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.database.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2.aspx